# Why is the Controller selecting the wrong view using CodeIgniter? Why has this gone to sleep?

Tags: codeigniter

I've asked this subject in another topic but that topic has gone to sleep and I'm unable to move forward with my project.

Before registration the site will ask the user to submit his or her email address. Upon submitting, the email address and a code are inserted into the database, and the code is sent to the email address, although I'm unable to test that because I'm only using localhost, and the code view is then opened. The code is to be stored in the pass_word field temporarily. All of that works good.

I then open the database and copy the code and paste it into the code view, of which view page also has a text box containing the email address. When the code view is submitted the Controller selects the wrong next page view, activating "else".

This is the coding:

Controller

```
class Code extends CI_Controller{
    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('tempub');
        $this->load->model('Code_model', 'code_model');
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $code = $this->input->post('code');
        $result = $this->code_model->find_code($email, $code);

        if ($result){
            $this->load->view('username');
        }else{
            // This view is selected when the code is correct
            $this->load->view('codeincorrect'); 
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
class Code_model extends CI_Model{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function find_code($email, $code){
        $this->db->select('user_id');
        $this->db->where('email_address', $email);
        $this->db->where('pass_word', $code);
        $code = $this->db->get('tbl_members');

        if ($code->result()){
            return $this->db->delete('pass_word', $code);
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
<div class="group">
    <style type="text/css"> .email { position: fixed; width: 100%; text-align: center; top: 30%; } </style>

    <div class="email">
        <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" style="width: 18%; height: 5mm"; />

        <style type="text/css"> .code { position: fixed; width: 100%; text-align: center; top: 55%; } </style>

        <div class="code">
            <input type="text" name="code" value="<?php echo set_value('code'); ?>" style="width: 15mm; height: 5mm"; />
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php echo form_open('code'); ?>

        <style type="text/css"> .submit { position: fixed; width: 100%; text-align: center; top: 65%; } </style>

        <div class="submit">
            <div class="group">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

Can somebody tell me where I'm going wrong?

Update 10/06/17

Thanks for the edit threeFatCat but it still selects view('codeincorrect');

I have edited your Controller coding as follows, to see what is being posted but I get a blank page (in other words nothing is being posted), which maybe the problem, or you maybe able to tell me what is wrong with that change. I have also tried the same test with $email but again get a blank page.

```
class Code extends CI_Controller{
public function index(){
$code = $this->input->post('code');
echo $code;
/*
    $this->load->view('tempub');
    $this->load->model('Code_model', 'code_model');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $code = $this->input->post('code');
    $result = $this->code_model->find_code($email, $code);

    if ($result){
        $this->load->view('username');
    }else{
        // This view is selected when the code is correct
        $this->load->view('codeincorrect');
    }
*/
}
}
```

I have also noticed the url does not change on the 1st posting and when the email address & code are inserted into the database. On that 1st posting the Controller coding loads view('code');

And on the 2nd posting (the subject posting) the Controller loads view('username'); or view('codeincorrect'); but the url is that of view('code'); These are the urls that appear as I go through the process;

(1) - localhost/email
(2) - localhost/email
(3) - localhost/code

I expect the urls to be as follows;

(1) - localhost/email
(2) - localhost/code
(3) - localhost/username or codeincorrect

I'm not sure if the above information can lead anybody to the problem.

Comment: return $this->db->delete('pass_word', $code); what you want using this ??

Comment: why do you have multiple `style` tags? why not put them in one `css` file or `style` tag?

Comment: If the code is correct I want it to be deleted from the password field, so that the next step can be completed, which is username & password.

Comment: I have found css complicated and isolated from the actual material it refers, and I prefer to have everything in one page, which appears to download quicker.

Comment: hi, first, you need to make all logic before you load the view in controller, then, if the info from form are correct in the first time, the code will be deleted, an if the same info are sending again the view you load are username, the view display are correct the log is incorrect

Comment: Thanks elddenmedio but I don't understand what you are trying to tell me. Can you rewrite the code in an answer?